# Azure AppService logging for .NET 5.0 application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have a .NET 5.0 Web API application that is hosted on Azure AppService (linux).
The problem is when I'm using a logger with a specific logging level the "Log Stream" in AppService is always showing all logs with the "Info" level.

Just an example:

```cs
[ApiController, Route("Logs")]
public sealed partial class LogsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<LogsController> Logger;

    public LogsController(ILogger<LogsController> logger)
    {
       this.Logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost(nameof(LogWarning))]
    public ActionResult LogWarning()
    {
        this.Logger.LogWarning("Simple warning");
        return this.Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost(nameof(LogError))]
    public ActionResult LogError()
    {
        this.Logger.LogError("Simple error");
        return this.Ok();
    }
}
```

But instead of expecated "Warning" and "Error" levels the "Log stream" shows:

```
2021-09-02T10:26:27.237547810Z: [INFO]  [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Rpm.Api.Controllers.Admin.LogsController[0]
2021-09-02T10:26:27.237614110Z: [INFO]        Simple warning
2021-09-02T11:10:47.290208822Z: [INFO]  [40m[1m[33mfail[39m[22m[49m: Rpm.Api.Controllers.Admin.LogsController[0]
2021-09-02T11:10:47.290261622Z: [INFO]        Simple error
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?
P.S.: All the app logging configuration is out of the box.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your log consumer configuration.

Comment: @Neil Any suggestion how to fix the problem?

Comment: What logger are you using?  Nlog? Can you show your startup.cs?

Comment: @Neil. I'm using the built-in asp.net logger. No any additional configuration.

Comment: To me, this looks like the log stream is produced by scraping the console, and so is not aware of the distinction between the `warn` and `fail` levels - you can see clearly in your sample that it has scraped them, along with the raw color codes.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using a logger with a specific logging level the "Log Stream" in
> AppService is always showing all logs with the "Info" level.

As tried repro in .NET 5.0 Web API application that is hosted on Azure AppService (linux) you can see all logs inside log stream because there is no option available in Linux to enable App service Logs  Only we can provide the file system details. As below screenshot.

[image]

Same way i tried repro with Windows and i can enable the App service logs which i want to see in log stream if there is any error, warning, information, verbose as below screenshot:

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:

. [Enable application logging (Linux/Container) | MS DOC .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer)

. [Application Insights logging with .NET | MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger)

.[Working with Log Stream and Azure App Services](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html)